# how to sort a multidimensional associative array(that contains WP post objects) by date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

usort($query, function($post_a, $post_b) {
// Compare the post_date of the posts, and if $post_b is newer, then it will be displayed first
return $post_b->post_date <=> $post_a->post_date;
});

```
    foreach($query as $post) {

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        ?>
    <div class="bbr-blog-outer-home">
        <div class="lmd-post-img">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="lmd-category">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php  echo $category->name; ?></a>
     </div>
    <div class="bbr-blog-inner">
     <p class="lmd-blog-date"><?php echo get_the_date('',$post); ?></p>
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h3>
     <p class="lmd-blog-author">
         <?php $lmd_author_id = $post->post_author; ?>
         <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $lmd_author_id ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more clarity to this question?  It doesn't really make sense at this point.

Comment: @HowardE thanks for seeing it. Actually, i want to show posts in chronological order. How to sort an assoc array(that contains wp post objects) as I am using the function get_categories().

Comment: Can you update the question to include your query please?